# Prove that $\cos20°\cos40°\cos60°\cos80°=\frac{1}{16}.$

Tags: trigonometry

After applying product to sum formulae, I got this far
$$\frac{\Bigl(1+2\cos(20)\Bigr)\Bigl(\cos(140)+\cos(20)\Bigr)}{8}=\frac{1}{16}.$$
How can I proceed further?

Comment: Are you saying you've proved it?

Comment: You can generalise this to $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{k}{2n+1}180^\circ\right)$ i.e. $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{k}{2n+1}\pi\right)=2^{-n}$ and here $n=4$.  Alternatives with $n=1,2,7,22$ also involve integer degree angles

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a proof, then ponder this:
\begin{align*}
&8\sin 20^\circ\cos20^\circ\cos40^\circ\cos80^\circ \\
= \, &4\sin 40^\circ\cos40^\circ\cos80^\circ \\
= \, &2\sin 80^\circ\cos80^\circ \\
= \, &\sin160^\circ=\sin20^\circ.
\end{align*}